# How to avoid receiving .NET 4+ through Windows Update?

Tags: windows-7, windows, .net-framework

For compatibility reasons, I need my system (Windows 7) **without** any .NET higher than 3.5.

Unfortunately, it seems that Windows Update will automatically update the .NET framework. While I can *uninstall* the framework again, Windows Update will keep buggering me with .NET 4 related updates and patches.

How can I set it up in such a way that .NET 3.5 *stays* the latest version of the .NET framework installed?

Comment: You can right-click the update and select `hide`, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Right-click *My Computer* and select `Properties`
- Click on `Windows Update` at the bottom the column to the left
- Click on the button `Search for updates`
- When you get the list of updates, right-click on the .NET Framework 4.x update
- Select `Hide update`

Now Windows won't remind you to update this again through Windows Update.

Answer (score 1):

Installing .Net 4 shouldn't effect an application targeted at .Net 3.5. This works with .Net 2 as well. They install side by side.

[Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/compatibility-of-net-framework-4-5/) is a reference to the Microsoft .Net framework blog article about it:

That being said, turning off automatic updates is an option that should prevent it. If you try to run any app targeted at 4 it'll prompt you to install the framework though.

Comment: +1 for the "why is this an issue?" style response from @Don.